# Windows Powershell: How to add server's public ssh key

Tags: ssh, powershell, putty

My system admin created a new droplet on digital ocean, and provided me with root username and password and a public key txt file.
when i try to access:

```
PS C:\Users\Simou> ssh root@x.x.x.217
```

I get this:

```
root@x.x.x.217: Permission denied (publickey).
```

since i'm used to powershell, i don't like using putty, even that putty provides the way to add a public ssh key.
I think the problem is that i need to add that ssh key somewhere (saw that linux users do that), but i don't know how to do it in powershell, and i don't find any solutions when searching, because all of the result is about generating a private/public pair and putting my public on the server, but my case is the inverse of that. i must put the servers public on my powershell.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are not connecting with PowerShell. You are connecting with [OpenSSH `ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh).

So you configure your private key the same way as with OpenSSH on Linux. If you generate your key pair with [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen), it gets automatically stored to the right place, where `ssh` will find it: `.ssh` folder in your Window profile in `%USERPROFILE%`, i.e. typically in `C:\Users\username\.ssh`. See also [Location of OpenSSH configuration file on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1537763/213663).

---

As others have commented, you cannot authenticate with server's public key. Hard to tell what you got actually. But it might be a server's host key, which you are supposed to use to verify that you are connecting to the correct server. See *my* article about [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).